# Deleting temporary rows and columns from 21-sheet workbook

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I've created a VBA code to delete extra rows and columns that were needed for initial calculations but are required to be removed before converting/importing a csv into a database. The code loops through 21 sheets and runs for about 4 minutes. Is this a decent run time or can it be shortened?

```
Public Sub Test()

Dim xWs As Worksheet
Set xWs = ActiveSheet
Dim Firstrow As Long
Dim Lastrow As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim CalcMode As Long
Dim ViewMode As Long

'SETTING DEPENDENT VALUES TO ABSOLUTE VALUES============================='

For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    xWs.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    xWs.UsedRange.Value = xWs.UsedRange.Value
Next

'DELETING ROWS BASED ON COLUMN B VALUES=================================='

For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    xWs.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Firstrow = xWs.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = xWs.UsedRange.Rows(xWs.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With xWs.Cells(Lrow, "B")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "0" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
Next

'DELETING DUPLICATE IP ADDRESSES=========================================='

With Sheets("IP-Unassigned")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With .Cells(Lrow, "H")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "1" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
End With

'DELETING EXTRA COLUMNS========================================================'

With Sheets("IP-FSW")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

With Sheets("IP-2070")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

With Sheets("IP-MNTR")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

With Sheets("IP-BBS")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

With Sheets("IP-DET")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

With Sheets("IP-TTR")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

With Sheets("IP-CCTV")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

With Sheets("IP-Unassigned")
    .Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    .DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Columns(16).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(15).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(14).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(13).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(12).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(11).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(10).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(9).EntireColumn.Delete
    Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
End With

'=========================================================================='

End Sub
```

Comment: [Avoid Active or Select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/2521004) statements at all cost.  Turn off calculations and [screen updating](http://www.excely.com/excel-vba/screen-updating.shtml).  You should see a big improvement with just doing these three things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Portland Runner gave some good hints in the comments. Your selection and view changes do not add any value to what you want to achieve. I was able to remove all of them without issues. When doing macro-based Excel manipulation, you should always consider:

- Setting `Application.ScreenUpdating` to `False`
- Setting `Application.Calculation` to `xlManual`
- Setting `Application.EnableEvents` to `False`
- Resetting all of these values when you have completed the work

Of course, there will be exceptions, but these should be rare.

Always remember `Option Explicit` in VBA

Looking at **absolute values**:

```
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    xWs.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    xWs.UsedRange.Value = xWs.UsedRange.Value
Next
```

This can simply be:

```
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.UsedRange.Value = xWs.UsedRange.Value
Next
```

Cleaner, easier to see what it does, and easier to maintain.

Looking at **Column B conditionals**:

```
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    xWs.Select
    ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
    ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
    xWs.DisplayPageBreaks = False
    Firstrow = xWs.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = xWs.UsedRange.Rows(xWs.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With xWs.Cells(Lrow, "B")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "0" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
Next
```

Can become:

```
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Firstrow = xWs.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = xWs.UsedRange.Rows(xWs.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1
        With xWs.Cells(Lrow, "B")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "0" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
Next
```

But I see repetition here. You can save your self a small loop. Admittedly, in the example you gave not a big issue but still a good practice to have.

**Combining the loops** - take note of the order in which I have done this. Do the most work first, and then do the simple clean-up. You could do it the other way (unless the `xlError` gets converted to a value on the way through?) but considering how much work is done in each step and how each step impacts on the amount of future work is a good habit.

```
For Each xWs In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Firstrow = xWs.UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
    Lastrow = xWs.UsedRange.Rows(xWs.UsedRange.Rows.count).Row ' this is yet another different way I have seen to get the last row!
    For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1 ' Good that you know to go backwards.
        With xWs.Cells(Lrow, "B")
            If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                If .Value = "0" Then .EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
    Next Lrow
    xWs.UsedRange.Value = xWs.UsedRange.Value ' Good that you know the simple way to convert formulas to values.
Next
```

**Deleting extra columns** - I see a lot of repetition here, and room for a subroutine.

```
Private Sub Delete78(xWs as Worksheet) 'Sheet could also include a Chart sheet
    xWS.Columns(8).EntireColumn.Delete
    xWS.Columns(7).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Interestingly, you could also do Col7.Del, and then Col7.Del again to achieve the same effect! But at least the way you have written it shows the intent to remove the two columns.

You main part of the code then becomes:

```
Delete78 Sheets("IP-FSW")
Delete78 Sheets("IP-2070")
Delete78 Sheets("IP-MNTR")
Delete78 Sheets("IP-BBS")
Delete78 Sheets("IP-DET")
Delete78 Sheets("IP-TTR")
Delete78 Sheets("IP-CCTV")
```

Still some repetition - and this could be fixed as well. But that can be another day. Or perhaps now. Because your last code block seems different but is really the same. So let us try a new subroutine.

```
Private Sub DeleteColumnBlock(xWs as Worksheet, LastColumn as Long, FirstColumn as Long) ' Get the user to enter the values in a logical order. I chose this way.
    Dim ColIterator as Long
    ' Do some input validation. If they have entered bad values, fix it.
    For ColIterator = LastColumn to FirstColumn Step -1
        xWs.Columns(ColIterator).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next ColIterator
End Sub
```

Because we are dealing with a contiguous block, you could also do the slightly more obscure - same effect, but slightly harder to see at a glance what you intend to do. Add some good comments if you intend to do this!

```
For ColIterator = FirstColumn to LastColumn
    xWs.Columns(FirstColumn).EntireColumn.Delete ' continually remove a column until the right number have been removed.
Next ColIterator
```

Your main part of that entire block then becomes:

```
DeleteColumnBlock Sheets("IP-FSW"), 8, 7
DeleteColumnBlock Sheets("IP-2070"), 8, 7
DeleteColumnBlock Sheets("IP-MNTR"), 8, 7
DeleteColumnBlock Sheets("IP-BBS"), 8, 7
DeleteColumnBlock Sheets("IP-DET"), 8, 7
DeleteColumnBlock Sheets("IP-TTR"), 8, 7
DeleteColumnBlock Sheets("IP-CCTV"), 8, 7
DeleteColumnBlock Sheets("IP-Unassigned"), 16, 8
```

### Summary

- Turn off the parts of Excel that you don't need when doing grunt
  work.
- Try to run through a loop only once, don't repeat your loops
  unless it is really really necessary.
- DRY (don't repeat yourself) - repetition is a sign that you can
  modularise some code making it easier to maintain.
- Use explicit addressing, avoid `Active` and `Select` unless there is
  no other way (e.g. copying sheets to a new workbook is a subroutine,
  not a function so `ActiveWorkbook` is the only way to immediately
  reference that new workbook).
- -- If you do `Activate` or `Select`, make sure your following code is    actually using those elements.
- -- And then consider if you can already reference it explicitly and do    so!

### Addendum

In my examples above, I provided a very mechanistic way of deleting columns (based on the OP code). Two more ways to do this without using a loop are to set a range:

- e.g. `xWS.Range(xWS.Cells(1,7), xWS.Cells(1,8).EntireColumn.Delete`
- Setting a union of the columns, and then deleting

Answer (score 2):

In the code bellow

- Condensed the OP code
- Stopped ScreenUpdating and Events
- Replaced row-by-row deletion in loops with bulk-deletion in AutoFilters

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub RemoveTmpData()
    Const WS_2COLS = "|IP-FSW|IP-2070|IP-MNTR|IP-BBS|IP-DET|IP-TTR|IP-CCTV|"
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.DisplayPageBreaks = False
            ws.UsedRange.Value2 = ws.UsedRange.Value2   'convert formulas to values
            If InStr(WS_2COLS, "|" & ws.Name & "|") > 0 Then ws.Columns("G:H").Delete
            RemoveTmpRows ws.UsedRange, 2, 0            'remove rows with val 0, in col B
        Next

        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("IP-Unassigned")
            RemoveTmpRows .UsedRange, 8, 1              'remove rows with val 1, in col H
            .UsedRange.Columns("H:P").Delete
        End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub RemoveTmpRows(ByRef rng As Range, ByVal colId As Long, ByVal crit As String)
    With rng
        .AutoFilter Field:=colId, Criteria1:=crit
        If .Columns(colId).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).CountLarge > 1 Then
            .Rows(1).Hidden = True
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
            .Rows(1).Hidden = False
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

---